# Record a video from surface view(bind video and camera preview)

Tags: java, android, camera, surfaceview, video-recording

**I want to record video of whatever happens on surface.**

I'm playing video on surface and showing camera preview over it. I want to record both in one video and export as .mp4. what should I do for it. your help would be much appreciated.

[image]

**Video and preview both are placed in one surface view.**

Comment: How do you make the video preview and camera preview on one surface? I didn't work on OpenGLES for a long time. Based on my experience, you need to use multiple OES textures to combine the preview, and use shared context to enable background recording. Take a look a this [sample project](https://github.com/google/grafika) and see if you can find any clue for your scenario.

Comment: @alijandro Thank you so much for your reply, but I'm beginner in OpenGLES, will you explain in deeply?

Comment: Have you tried using MediaProjection? That allows you to record the screen with ImageReader so I think you can record the contents with media projection.

Comment: @FurkanYurdakul No, I think that is record whole screen of device, but I want only surface activity, is it possible with Media Projection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1) I'm highly recommend to refer **grafika** project from Google's repository in [Github](https://github.com/google/grafika/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/android/grafika/RecordFBOActivity.java) and try with `RecordFBOActivity`.

(2) see `EZFilter` repositoey in [Github](https://github.com/uestccokey/EZFilter).

and

(3) `RecordableSurfaceview` in [Github](https://github.com/spaceLenny/recordablesurfaceview)

May this will much helpful to you.

Comment: Thank you so much for this advice, you save my day, your information are so helpful for me, thanks a lot!

Comment: I'm glad to here this! Carry on.

Comment: check my updated answer with links, Enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

try this solution with your clip result which is getting in the segmentation result from ML kit.

```
@ColorInt
    private Bitmap maskColorsFromByteBuffer(ByteBuffer byteBuffer, int maskWidth, int maskHeight) {
        @ColorInt int[] colors = new int[maskWidth * maskHeight];
        for (int i = 0; i < maskWidth * maskHeight; i++) {
            float backgroundLikelihood = 1 - byteBuffer.getFloat();
            if (backgroundLikelihood > 0.9) {
                colors[i] = Color.GREEN;
            } else if (backgroundLikelihood > 0.2) {
                // Linear interpolation to make sure when backgroundLikelihood is 0.2, the alpha is 0 and
                // when backgroundLikelihood is 0.9, the alpha is 128.
                // +0.5 to round the float value to the nearest int.
                int alpha = (int) (182.9 * backgroundLikelihood - 36.6 + 0.5);
                colors[i] = Color.argb(alpha, 0, 255, 0);
            }
        }


        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(maskWidth, maskHeight, this.bitmap.getConfig());
        Paint p = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        canvas.drawBitmap(this.bitmap, 0, 0, p);
        p.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.DST_OUT));
        canvas.drawBitmap(Bitmap.createBitmap(colors, maskWidth, maskHeight, this.bitmap.getConfig()), 0, 0, p);


//        canvas.drawPaint(p);

        return bitmap;
    }
```